# margin-bottom not working with percentage based heights

Tags: css

I am unable to add a *margin-bottom* property to an element which has been stretched to match the browsers height. Example:

**HTML**:

```
<body>
    <section></section>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
  html, body {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      background-color: #FFF;
  }
  section {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 50%;
      background-color: #000;
  }
```

Neither pixels nor percentage values work to extend the margin-bottom property.

Attached is a jsfiddle illustrating my problem: [margin-bottom problem](http://jsfiddle.net/XsJH8/)

Thanks!

Comment: It works, it seems like you want `padding` and not `margin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine.

just add another

```
<section></section>
```

to see the margin

```
<body>
<section>hello</section>
<section>yo</section>
</body>
```